# Brand new purchase

Tags: piano

Just bought a Yamaha YPT-270 Digital Keyboard. Used to play on a baby grand and was pretty good. Could never play classical. Haven't played in years and don't have the piano anymore.  Need lots and lots of practice! Did I make a mistake with 61 keys? How do I adapt?

Comment: If you don't need weighted keys, the PSR-EW310 has more keys, touch sensitivity, and (I think) a better piano sound. If you bought new, consider an exchange?

Comment: Do you feel like you made a mistake? Are you enjoying playing your keyboard or not? Do you have an option to return it? Is budget a consideration for you?

Comment: Does the smaller range bother you for the type of music you enjoy playing?

Comment: Thanks! I'm sending the Yamaha back on my next day off. Bought a Casio CDP-S100 today. 88 weighted keys! Sounds and plays much more like a piano. So far I'm very happy with it!  I don't even sound as bad was i first thought!

Answer (score 6):

Most likely consider you've made a mistake. After getting used to the feel of a baby grand, the Yamaha will feel like you're pressing switches - which you are. The touch sensitivity isn't anything like you used to play, making it difficult.

There's also the lack of a couple of octaves - which will lose you the richness of the lower section at least. O.k., it has lots of sounds that your grand couldn't make, but in reality you'll need to spend a lot more for a keyboard that will last you more than a few weeks before you agree it wasn't the right one to purchase.

True, it also takes up little room, and can be played almost silently, but so can so many other keyboards with *weighted keys*. Homework time again...

Comment: "The touch sensitivity isn't anything like you used to play" - certainly true: there's no touch sensitivity at all on this Yamaha model.

Comment: @topomorto - the blurb does say there are  'velocity sensitive keys', which obviously isn't going to be anything like a grand.

Comment: aha ok thanks... I'm obviously getting confused between my Yamahas